# How to use Oracle Installation Prerequisites on Redhat Linux 6.5?

Tags: linux, oracle

Today I get error below when install Oracle 11gR2 on Redhat Linux 6.5.

I follow instruction in this link: http://public-yum.oracle.com/

After I call this command:

**# yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall**

=> ok

**# yum update**

=> I got these errors:

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-19.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           Requires: libreport-python = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Removing: libreport-python-2.0.9-19.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Updated By: libreport-python-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.5-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.5-20.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.5-20.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.5-20.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.el6_3.2.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.el6_4.1.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-19.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           Requires: libreport-compat = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Removing: libreport-compat-2.0.9-19.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Updated By: libreport-compat-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.el6_4.1.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-19.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           Requires: libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Removing: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-19.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-19.el6
           Updated By: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.5-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.5-20.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.5-20.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.5-20.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.el6_3.2.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.el6_4.1.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IT seems yum is confused about having 2 different sources (RedHat and Oracle) for `libreport-plugin-reportuploader`, `libreport-compat` and `libreport-python`. Why not installing them by hand ?

Comment: Thanks Ouki. I'm new to this and could you please give me instruction how to install them by hand. I tried 'yum install libreport-plugin-reportuploader' but it still failed.

Comment: Use `yum remove` as adviced by Michael. Then you can have a look at a real [Oracle 11g installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#CEGHFFGG) for RedHat & others .

Comment: Thanks Ouki. I use Oracle Installation Prerequisites because it is auto config kit making by Oracle. You can read more about it's profit at:  [Using Oracle Preinstall RPM with Red Hat 6](http://flashdba.com/install-cookbooks/using-oracle-preinstall-rpm-with-red-hat-6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That web site does not explain how to install Oracle Database. Rather it explains how to install Oracle Linux, a clone of Red Hat Enterprise Linux. These packages are obviously conflicting with each other.

To resolve the problem, remove the Oracle Linux repository files that you had installed from that site, then run `yum distro-sync` to repair your RHEL system.

Comment: Thanks you, Michael. After hours finding way to remove above errors, it works now! (and I installed databases without any error).